# WPF Datagrid event get Cell source

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I'm a noob to WPF and datagrids, I'd appreciate a pointer for setting up a mouse over event.

I'd like to change the cell value of a cell in a datagrid when the user mouse overs - the cell contains an integer value.

I've set up a datagrid, bound it to a class - this all appears to work fine.

I've now used the MouseEnter event, but I can't get the the class property to change it.

Any help would be great (apologies if I've used the wrong terminology...)
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a `CellStyle` with an `EventTrigger` to handle the `MouseEnter` for the cells:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="..." Binding="{Binding YourProperty}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="OnMouseEnter" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

In the event handler, you cast the `DataContext` of the `DataGridCell` to your data object type and set the property:

```
private void OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)sender;
    YourClass obj = cell.DataContext as YourClass;
    if (obj != null)
        obj.YourProperty = 100;
}
```

Also make sure that your class implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to be able to raise change notifications to the view:

```
public class YourClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _yourProperty;
    public int YourProperty
    {
        get { return _yourProperty; }
        set { _yourProperty = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```